# How to close the dialog by clicking cancel key?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

In my laravel 5.6/vue.js 2.5.7 / vuetify": "^1.0.8" application I use 
dialogs as written here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs

I wonder if there is a way to close the dialog by clicking cancel key?

MODIFIED :
As that is vuetify, my dialog definition looks like  :

```
<v-footer app>
    <v-dialog scrollable v-model="new_registered_users_dialog_visible"  @keyup.esc="new_registered_users_dialog_visible=false">
        <v-card>
```

and inserting keyup event as above has no effect

I tried to insert alert code in event:

```
<v-footer app>
    <v-dialog scrollable v-model="new_registered_users_dialog_visible"  @keyup.esc="alert(-1);new_registered_users_dialog_visible=false">
        <v-card>
```

also no alerts

Which is the right way ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I hope this should work for you:

```html
<v-dialog @keydown.esc="new_registered_users_dialog_visible = false">
```

You can check this link [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/1326) that discusses the same use case as yours.

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED block

Comment: @mstdmstd I've edited the listener event which you should bind to. I was able to achieve with the keyup event if i was binding it to the top level div or with the body tag but that didn't work at the dialog level.

Comment: So looks like no decision? That is a pity! Such a small feature, but very annoying...